# Windows 7 universal and updated ISO

Tags: deployment

I would like to make universal Windows 7 SP1 instalation ISO with following options:

- Lets you choose edition you would like to install (all except Enterprise)
- One ISO for 64bit editions and another for 32bit editions

As far as I know that this is just the matter of removing "ef.cfg" from "sources" folder.
But what if I want to make these ISO's with latest updates for windows?
How can I capture install.wim, that contains up to date windows for all versions?

Comment: Use http://www.vlite.net/. It works for Windows 7 too.

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite what you're after, but if you plan on installing Windows with this ISO on the same network as a server of yours, the most microsoft-approved way to wrangle this is with [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791.aspx) (free), in which you can add and serve up as many different configurations of whatever operating systems you want. MDT makes a small ISO that you boot from on a computer, which then connects to your MDT server and installs the version/configuration of your choice from there. It's a steeper learning curve during setup than something like [RT7Lite](http://www.rt7lite.com/) or [nLite](http://www.vlite.net/) (single ISO customization utilities), but MDT is in my experience much more reliable and customizable than things like that. Also, the documentation bundled with MDT, and the available third-party guides on how to get started with it, are all great.

All of my experiences with customization utilities have been bad; no matter how little customization I need to do, I always have system stability issues afterwards. MDT, maybe because it's Microsoft-native, and less of a hack than the alternatives, has no such problems in my experience. Not only can MDT let you build an updated image, you can use DISM to apply updates and inject drivers into the wim files it uses. You could even use it to install applications after the install, and automate windows updates.